# How to edit a AppxManifest.xml in WindowsApp folder?

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, uwp

I want to change the appearance on tiles of some UWP apps on Win 10, so I tried to edit the AppxManifest.xml of those apps but failed. All these files are in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\`

I have already taken the ownership of all the subfolders of WindowsApps, and give "everyone" the full control. I have also tried saving the file elsewhere, and then replacing it with the edited version, but I always receive the warning: "Destination folder access denied: you need permission to perform this action". So is there really no way to change AppxManifest.xml of Windows apps?

[warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IQsI.png)

Comment: Monkeying with the ownership of WindowsApps is to be avoided!

Answer (score 2):

Windows does not let you access the WindowsApps folder and its contents by default. You need to get permission for this.

Open command prompt as Administrator there. Now run the command `takeown /f FolderName`. Then run the command `icacls FolderName /grant Administrators:F`. Now you will get the full permission to the folder. You can do this for each file or folder you need.

To do this in bulk you can use powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem "FolderPath" -Recurse | Foreach { takeown /f $_.Fullname; icacls $_.Fullname /grant Administrators:F }
```